# Query at Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using Sonata to make a backoffice and at configureFormFields, I want do a query to return some values. The query is well done and returns values when I use var_dump, but at the form I always get "Class does not exist". Can you help me?

Here is the code:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
      /* @var $queryBuilder \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = $this->getModelManager()
            ->getEntityManager('EBCoreKernelBundle:Campaign\Campaign')
            ->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder->select('cmp.id, cmp.name')
                 ->from('EBCoreKernelBundle:Campaign\Campaign', 'cmp');

          /* @var $templateList Template[] */
    $templateList = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();

         var_dump($templateList);

    $formMapper
        ->add('name','sonata_type_model',  array('required' => true, 'query' => $queryBuilder));


}
```

Comment: What error do you get? I.e. which class does not exist?

Comment: may be problem  with
`->from('EBCoreKernelBundle:Campaign\Campaign', 'cmp');` this line.
use `->from('EBCoreKernelBundle:Campaign', 'cmp');` if your Campaign entity is in Entity folder of EBCoreKernelBundle

Comment: @bsnrijal that didn't work

Comment: @JonWinstanley i don't know. It only says that the class does not exist

Comment: you are fetching templatelist and i think you want to display template list in formmapper.Try using: 
`->add('name','sonata_type_model',  
array('required' => true, 'class'=> 'EBCoreKernelBundle:Campaign\Campaign','property'=> 'Your property name', 'query_builder' => $templateList));`

Comment: @bsnrijal i found another way to do this with a controller and some extra objects. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

$entity = new \Nnx\AbpBundle\Entity\Truc();

$query = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager($entity)->createQuery('SELECT t FROM Nnx\AbpBundle\Entity\Truc t ORDER BY t.lib ASC')->execute();

Comment: You should develop a little bit your answer, not just code without context.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html

> **query** defaults to null. You can set this to a QueryBuilder instance in
>   order to define a custom query for retrieving the available options.

So, let's give it a query builder:

```
        $queryBuilder = $this->getModelManager()
           ->getEntityManager(Category::class)
           ->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->select('c')
           ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')
           ->orderBy('c.title', 'ASC')
        ;

        $formMapper->add('toto', ModelType::class, array(
           'query' => $queryBuilder
        ))
```